# Translation files in different locale folder by side ID

Tags: django

Is there a way to create different locale folder based on SITE_ID?

something like:

```
- project
  - app1
  - app2
  - locale_1 (where 1,2 are my SITE_IDS)
  - locale_2
```

Is there a specific command arg to do what I'm asking?

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your "locale" folders inside application directories.

For example:

```
- project
  - app1
    - locale
  - app2
    - locale
```

Comment: I need to separate folders by site not by app.